# how to guess a particluar solution of a second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve the following equation?
$$y''(t)-\frac{2}{t}y'(t)+\left(1+\frac{2}{t^2}\right)y(t)=0.$$
It is well-known that if we have a particular solution $y_1 (t)$ of ODE above, then we can obtain another particular solution $y_2 (t)$ by Abel formula hence general solution by $y(t)=c_1 y_1 +c_2 y_2$. How can I guess the $y_1 (t)$?

Comment: If you are smart enough to find $y_1$ then you are surely smart enough to guess $y_2$ and Abel's formula is useless in this case. The only way to solve this DE is to solve it without guessing a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a second-order linear ordinary differential equation. Rewrite it,
$$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}-\frac{2\frac{dy}{dt}}{t}+\frac{(t^2+2)y}{t^2}=0$$
Integrating Factor with $\mu(t)=t$ and substitute $y(t)=\mu(t)v(t)$ will eliminate the first order term. Sometimes this can lead to a simpler equation to solve. Can you go from here$?$
$$y(t)=t(c_1\cos(t)+c_2\sin(t))$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I could obtain your last answer. I have a question. Why do you choose y(t) this way? How can I guess that?

Answer (score 0):

$$y''(t)-\frac{2}{t}y'(t)+\left(1+\frac{2}{t^2}\right)y(t)=0$$
Substitute $u=\frac {y'}{y}$
$$u'+u^2-\frac{2}{t}u=-\left(1+\frac{2}{t^2}\right)$$
$$\left(u-\frac 1t\right)'+\left(u-\frac{1}{t}\right)^2=-1$$
$$v'+v^2=-1$$
That's  easy to solve.
$$v=-\tan (t+c_1)$$
$$\frac {y'}{y}=\frac 1 t-\tan (t+c_1)$$
$$(\ln y )'=\frac 1 t-\tan (t+c_1)$$
Integrate:
$$\ln y =\ln t+\ln \cos (t+c_1)+c_2$$
$$\implies y(t)=c_2t\cos (t+c_1)$$